# convert '../../' into 'path/path/'

Tags: php

Is there a way to convert a path that looks like `../../../` into `path/path/path`, I want to make a search class but got to thinking that anyone could pass in the `../` format instead of `path/` and return a list of the files that are found.

I started to approach this by using `preg_replace()` to find and replace everything up until it matches the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the path being passed. But the only solves the `path/path/path` problem.

How would I approach the `../../../` problem?

Comment: Do you need `../` in your search path? The best way would be to disallow using it and show some error message instead of trying to make it usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about realpath?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: i know that, but my method grabs the `$path` variable and uses it in its recursive search.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear about the ask but probably this will work for you:

```
$path = '../../..';
$path = str_replace(realpath($path) . '/', '', getcwd());
```

Comment: well the problem is not me, its the security approaches that who ever uses this script will need. I know what to do with it, but other people might upload the script and get the output not desired by the servers owner